# Swift 2 Framework Project + Console target: this target might include its own product

Tags: xcode, swift, frameworks

Trying to create (Xcode 7 beta) framework project with console application target for OS X, got this message:

```
Check dependencies
Unable to run command 'PBXCp TestFramework.framework' - this target might include its own product.
```

Included framework as dependency, set up copy framework phase.

Sample project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kqnmwpajma7ztxw/TestFramework.zip?dl=0

Comment: I've encountered the exactly same problem. Have you got anything?

Comment: Same here, could you solve it? Any leads?

Comment: This seems to be related to building a binary that's not distributed in a  bundle (Can't copy a `.framework` folder into a file, after all)